# How do I read a text file's content and write it to a <div> using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**Problem:** How do I read content from a text file (saved on the server along with the html page) and write that content into the *'innerHTML'* of a  on the HTML page?

**Context:** I want to create a static website which functions as a blog. However, I'd like there to be just one post page, and each post is read from a text file and written into the main div of the page. The content in the text file will be marked up with the required html tags so that they function like html when written into the div (but the file itself will be saved as a *.txt* file).

Ideally, the text file should be able to be stored in a folder that isn't the same as that of the html page (and/or script file) calling it.

**Additional Info:** Most solution I've come across have to do with reading a file uploaded by the user. This is not what I'm trying to understand. I'm trying to understand how to read from a text file stored as part of the site's assets.

Comment: You do it the same way. It doesn't matter how the file got onto the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

```js
(async () => {
    const text = await (await fetch("/path/to/the/text/file.txt")).text();
    div.innerHTML = text;
})();
```

By the way, unless the file contains HTML markup, I recommend you to use `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML`. That way, characters like `<` are not interpreted specially.